# Android recyclerview poor performance after API 27 to 29 Migration

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Migrated app to support latest API 29. All has gone very well, app functions correctly, except for one perplexing issue;  A `recyclerview` is populated using a SQLite query, which may retrieve 500+ records, and displays the result in a detail activity that looks like this.

[image]

This has always worked fine on API 27 with the detail activity opened & populated almost instantly, while the sql call, activity code and layout hasn't changed in 5 years.  However, on the **API 29** version, using the **same code**, the app takes **3+ seconds to display the same data**

After much testing and reading [Slow Rendering](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render#java), I think I've nailed it down to `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0` in API 29 taking much longer to build the output for the activity UI, possibly due to my poor coding and/or layout structure.

This is my `R.layout.msgh_detail` populated by the .java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/msgh_detail_list" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/replyCard"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:maxLength="250"
            android:ems="10"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:id="@+id/msg_reply"
            android:hint="@string/msg_reply_hint" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/replyCard"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the include `R.layout.msgh_detail_list_item` via .java `ViewHolder`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.97"
        android:id="@+id/DayMMdd"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:hint="@string/day_mth_dte" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/arrivaltime"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/Hour_min" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:src="@drawable/status_1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:longClickable="false" />

</LinearLayout>


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/detail_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#ccecf9">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:textColorLink="#009933"
            android:layout_weight="0.97"
            android:text="@string/test_msg" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Clearly, there's quite a lot going on here and, frankly, I'm amazed it works so well, or at least it did until androidx and API version 29 came along..!

QUESTION: The issue is that the app gets exceedingly slow on a 300+ recordset and I'm a bit stumped on how to fix it...

**LATER FIXED!:** Revised `R.layout.msgh_detail` subsequent to tip by @martin-zeitler that now seems to work properly and load data pretty much instantly.

Removed entire `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView` block and replaced with `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` from the include layout (now discarded).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/detail_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/replyCard"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:maxLength="250"
            android:ems="10"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:id="@+id/msg_reply"
            android:hint="@string/msg_reply_hint" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/replyCard"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Yes,This happens if you use androidx.

Comment: The code you should provide should be **minimal**: [mcve]

Comment: Ok @rob revised it shorter for you :o)

Comment: Don't do it for me. **It's a requirement** as I showed you in the link to SO rules.

Comment: Oh @rob was hoping to have the minus removed -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also noticed that once, that it became quite sluggish ...

The problem is likely that `NestedScrollView` > `LinearLayout` > `RecyclerView`.

Also that `include` is pretty useless, with one single node contained.... you have to nest it like this:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:measureAllChildren="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        tools:listitem="@layout/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:splitMotionEvents="false"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"/>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: @rangi bugs like this are hard to track down, when only trial and error can be applied.

Comment: @rangi the `NestedScrollView` is required when having a `AppBarLayout`. your's just lacked attribute `app:layout_behavior` ...won't edit anything.

Comment: Thanks @martin-zeitler Oh, well it still lagged, so I dumped the `NestedScrollView` completely and it all sprang into life (see revised layout on end of my question). Your tip was valid, set me on a path, it worked... thanks very much. Cheers, Simone